# How to upload a file to the server (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, ejs

Don't upload photos to the server, how to solve this problem? 
on the page `index.ejs` a photo gallery should be generated from the added entries. The entry contains a photo. The entry is added, but the photo doesn't load. 
[project (GitHub)](https://github.com/vitarunaeva/vlgplace)
app/routes.js:

```js
var upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
        limits: {fileSize: 7},
        fileFilter: function (req, file, cd) {
            checkFileType(file, cd);
        }
    }).single('filePhoto');
    function checkFiletType(file, cd) {
        const fileTypes = /jpeg|jpg/;
        const extname = fileTypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
        const mimetype = fileTypes.test(file.mimetype);

        if (extname && mimetype) {
            return cd(null, true);
        } else {
            cd('Error: only JPEG or JPG!')
        }
        
        var Photo = require('../app/models/photo');

    module.exports = function (app, passport) {
      app.get('/', function (req, res,next) {
            Photo.find({}, function (error, photos) {
                var photoList = '';
                     res.render('index.ejs', {photoList: photos});
            });
        });
     }
     app.post('/addPhoto', function (req, res, next) {
            next();
             }, function (req, res) {
            var newPhoto = new Photo(req.body);
            newPhoto.save().then(function (response) {
                console.log('here', response);
                res.status(200).json({code: 200, message: 'OK'});
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.error('new photo error', error);
            });
        },function (req, res) {
            Photo.find({}, function (error, photos) {
                res.send('index.ejs', {
                    photoList: photos
                });
            });
        });
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your `upload` var as middleware to your upload route.

Here is a snippet from how I have done it previously:

```
// Route:

const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

router.post('/upload', upload.single('photo'), ImageController.upload);


// Image Controller:

upload(req, res){

  console.log("file", req.file)

}
```

When I post my image, I make sure I call it `photo` to match the key word I used in my multer middleware:

So I create my form data like so:

```
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('photo', {
  uri: data.uri,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
});

axios.post(`${SERVER}/images/upload`, 
    formData: formData,
    { headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      } 
    })
    .then(response => console.log("response", response))
    .catch(err => console.log('err', err))
```